# How can I transform integer column results into strings in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I need to write a function that will transform the results of a column called "store_id" in a table. I want to transform the integer 1 into "Store 1" and 2 into "Store 2", but I get errors no matter what I enter.

I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform_store_id()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE detailed_sales
  SET store_id = CASE store_id
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'store 1'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'store 2'
                    ELSE store_id::text
                  END;
END;
$$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I get

> "ERROR: column "store_id" is of type integer but expression is of type
> text"

So, I tried incorporating CAST and TO_CHAR with varying errors.

Comment: Seems like your column is of type integer? Of course, it's not allowed to update an integer column to a varchar or text value. You would need to alter the column type before. What is the purpose of this strange idea? What do you really want to do?

Comment: It's an assignment where we have to write a function that will transform a column. Nothing I'm trying is working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should assign the transformed values to a new TEXT column instead of updating the existing 'store_id' column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform_store_id()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE detailed_sales ADD COLUMN transformed_store_id TEXT;

  UPDATE detailed_sales
  SET transformed_store_id = CASE store_id
                               WHEN 1 THEN 'store 1'
                               WHEN 2 THEN 'store 2'
                               ELSE store_id::text
                             END;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: It worked!! THANK YOU!! I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to create a new column to do this. You can change the column in place.

Answer (score 0):

You  need first change the column type

```
CREATE TABLE detailed_sales(store_id  int)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO detailed_sales VALUEs (1),(2), (3)
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 3
> ```

```
ALTER TABLE detailed_sales 
ALTER COLUMN  store_id TYPE   TEXT;
```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE
> ```

```
  UPDATE detailed_sales
  SET store_id = CASE store_id
                    WHEN '1' THEN 'store 1'
                    WHEN '2' THEN 'store 2'
                    ELSE store_id::text
                  END;
```

> ```
> UPDATE 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8AT5jp2u)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have demonstrated that there is no need for a function at all.

Another approach might be to use [`GENERATED`](https://severalnines.com/blog/overview-generated-columns-postgresql/) ([manual](https://V)) - aka `COMPUTED`, `DERIVED` and also confusingly, `VIRTUAL` - columns (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/R4M2k2f9)).

```
CREATE TABLE detailed_sales(store_id  int)
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO detailed_sales VALUES (1),(2), (3)
```

Add our `GENERATED` column:

```
ALTER TABLE detailed_sales 
ADD COLUMN store TEXT 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
(
  CASE store_id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'store 1'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'store 2'
    ELSE store_id::TEXT
  END
) STORED;
```

And, without further ado, we run:

```
SELECT 
   store_id,
   store,
   PG_TYPEOF(store_id),
   PG_TYPEOF(store)
FROM 
   detailed_sales;
```

Result:

```
store_id   store  pg_typeof  pg_typeof
       1 store 1    integer       text
       2 store 2    integer       text
       3       3    integer       text
```

And our `store 1`, `store 2`, &c. "magically" appear!

The [`PG_TYPEOF()`](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-get-the-column-type-using-pg_typeof-function-in-postgresql/) ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-info.html)) function is, of course, not necessary - just for demonstration purposes!

Note that the `STORED` keyword is compulsory - most servers have two storage modes for `GENERATED` columns - `STORED` (on disk) and `VIRTUAL` (computed on the fly - i.e. when requested) - hence the remark about calling the column itself `VIRTUAL` being confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**Caution the below assumes you want to change the field type in place**. See further cautions below.

```
CREATE TABLE store_test(id integer, store_id integer);

\d store_test 
              Table "public.store_test"
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id       | integer |           |          | 
 store_id | integer |           |  

INSERT INTO store_test VALUES (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2);


ALTER TABLE store_test
    ALTER COLUMN store_id TYPE varchar
    USING
        CASE WHEN store_id::varchar = '1' THEN
            'store1'
        WHEN store_id::varchar = '2' THEN
            'store2'
        ELSE
           store_id::varchar
        END;

\d store_test 
                   Table "public.store_test"
  Column  |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id       | integer           |           |          | 
 store_id | character varying |     

SELECT * FROM store_test ;

 id | store_id 
----+----------
  1 | store2
  2 | store1
  3 | store1
  4 | store2
```

If this is a large table it could take some time. You also need to make sure there are not triggers on the table that rely on the old column type. Same for any FOREIGN KEY relationships this column may be part of.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column datatype from integer to text first and then a simple update would do the trick. In the update we use the concatenate for the store_id-s requested. An index on store_id would speed up the query.

Step 1

```
ALTER TABLE detailed_sales ALTER COLUMN store_id TYPE TEXT;
```

Step 2

```
update detailed_sales 
  set store_id = 'Store ' || store_id 
where  store_id in ('1','2');
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/EAhKi-JH)

---

I suggest you keep store_id as it is , you can add the keyword 'Store' at the time you retrieve the data (during the select)

Comment: Why not do: `set store_id = 'Store ' || store_id `   >>

Comment: @Luuk right , I do not know why I have complicated the concatenation , thanks for the insight

Answer (score -1):

You can add a new column with the text data type and update it with the required values in order to change the "store_id" column in your table. try the following code. In this code the original "store_id" column is preserved while a new "store_name" column is created and updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform_store_id()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Add a new column called "store_name" with text data type
  ALTER TABLE detailed_sales ADD COLUMN store_name TEXT;
  
  -- Update the "store_name" column based on the "store_id" values
  UPDATE detailed_sales
  SET store_name = CASE store_id
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Store 1'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'Store 2'
                    ELSE store_id::text
                  END;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: This was rejected because I need to transform a column, not just add one. I tried to figure out the code to change it to alter column, but that came up with errors.